# Is my proof that the Euler number is equal to the sum of infinite series correct and rigorous?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

We know that $e = \lim_{n\to \infty}  (1 + {1\over n})^n $. Now, If we expand $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$, we get
$$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\frac1{n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}\cdot\frac1{k!} = \frac{1}{n^0} + \frac{n}{n}+ \sum_{k=2}^n \frac1{k!}\prod_{t= 1}^{k-1} \Big(1 - \frac{t}{n}\Big)$$
On taking limits on both sides, we get
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = 1 + 1 +  \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k!}\prod_{t= 1}^{k-1} \Big(1 - \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{t}{n}\Big)$$
Now, the above summation can be written as
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = 1 + 1 +  \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}, k \neq 1}\frac1{k!}\prod_{t= 1}^{k-1} \Big(1 - \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{t}{n}\Big)$$
Now, since $k$ is a natural number, $t$ is also a natural number. So, $\lim_{n \to \infty}t/n=0$ in the above equation. So, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = 1 + 1 +  \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}, k \neq 1}\frac1{k!}$$
The above equation can be written as
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = 1 + 1 +  \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}
 \frac1{k!} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
 \frac1{k!}.$$
This completes the proof. So, My question is, is my proof correct and rigorous?

Comment: No, your proof is not rigorous. Using $\infty$ as a number is a clear sign of that.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem#Example for a rigorous proof using Tannery's theorem.

Comment: @jjagmath ; Thanks for pointing that out. I have made the corrections. Please    See it.

Comment: You need to justify passing the limit oparation inside the sum and extending the sum to infinity. That is the non-trivial part of the proof.

Comment: Using $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ as a quantity is not rigorous, because $\lim_{n\to\infty} n=+\infty$ and $+\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: Noticing that in one summand we have $k=n$ and in one of its factors we have $t=k-1=n-1$, it doesn't make sense to claim we can consider $\left(1-\frac tn\right)$ as approaching $1$.

Comment: By this sort of argument, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} = 0$. But the actual value is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac 12$.

Comment: @aschepler ; Thank you very much! You just gave a perfect example.

Comment: @aschepler;  I would very much appreciate if you could help me find out why $\lim_{ n \to \infty } \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)  \neq \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} f(k)$, where $ f(k)$ is an arbitrary function defined for all $ k \in \mathbb{N}$,?

Comment: In your last comment there is equality provided the series is convergent. The OP statement can be obtained by the squeeze principle.

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} f(k)$$ is different from $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(n,k) \neq \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n,k)$$